# Turtle X drawing simplification

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Just creating a python program that creates a function named letterX, that ... well makes an X. The two lines must be 90 degrees from each other. The pointer ends at the initial position.

I solved this pretty easily, just wondering if you can put this into a loop or just simplify it. I don't know how since i have to change directions differently rather than looping over the same code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
s = turtle.Screen()

def letterX(t,length):
    t.down()
    t.right(45)
    t.forward(length/2)
    t.right(180)
    t.forward(length)
    t.right(180)
    t.forward(length/2)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(length/2)
    t.right(180)
    t.forward(length)
    t.right(180)
    t.forward(length/2)
    t.right(45)
    t.up()
letterX(t,100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd measure turtle efficiency as minimizing drawing -- your turtle is redrawing things it has already drawn, so let's optimize that:

```
def letterX(t, length):

    half_length = length / 2
    hypotenuse = (2 * half_length**2)**0.5

    t.pendown()
    t.right(45)
    t.forward(half_length)
    t.left(135)

    t.penup()
    t.forward(hypotenuse)
    t.pendown()

    t.left(135)
    t.forward(length)
    t.right(135)

    t.penup()
    t.forward(hypotenuse)
    t.pendown()

    t.right(135)
    t.forward(half_length)
    t.left(45)
    t.penup()
```

However, if you really want minimal amount of code and a loop, consider:

```
def letterX(t, length):

    for angle in range(-135, 136, 90):
        mock = t.clone()
        mock.left(angle)
        mock.forward(length / 2)
        mock.hideturtle()
```

If you're looking for speed, and truly cryptic code, consider stamping:

```
def letterX(t, length):

    t.shapesize(length / 10, 1 / 10)  # assuming default turtle image

    for angle in range(-45, 91, 135):
        t.tilt(angle)
        t.stamp()

    t.tilt(-45)
    t.shapesize(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is figuring out repeatable units.  Since you want the turtle restored after all units, it is easiest here to restore it after each unit.

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
s = turtle.Screen()

def line(t, length, angle):
    half = length/2
    t.left(angle)
    t.forward(half)
    t.right(180)
    t.down()
    t.forward(length)
    t.up()
    t.right(180)
    t.forward(half)
    t.right(angle)

def letterX(t,length):
    for angle in (45, 135):
        line(t, length, angle)

letterX(t,100)
```